# How to do async await function imports/SP EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a function imports a stored procedure, but I want to make it as async. How could I do that?

Any ideas?

```
public static async Task<List<ObtenerLayoutPor_Result>> GenerarArchivoPorBanco()
{
    List<ObtenerLayoutPor_Result> result = new List<ObtenerLayoutPorBanco_Result>();

    try
    {
        using (CobranzaEntities db = new CobranzaEntities())
        {
            return Task.Run(() => db.ObtenerLayoutPor(96)).GetAwaiter(); //one try

            result = await db.ObtenerLayoutPor(96); //second try
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What's the return type of `ObtenerLayoutPor`?

Comment: I usually put the code into a background worker.  The background worker is async.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ObjectResult<ObtenerLayoutPorBanco_Result>

Comment: Don't throw a new exception in a catch.  Either use `throw;` (to rethrow the original exception) or throw a new exception with the caught exception as an inner exception.  Or, even better, why catch anything?  You should let the the exception bubble up until someone is able to handle it (which might be no-one).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
public static Task<List<ObtenerLayoutPor_Result>> GenerarArchivoPorBanco()
{
  return Task.Run(()=>{ // no await here and function as a whole is not async

        using (CobranzaEntities db = new CobranzaEntities())
        {
            return db.ObtenerLayoutPor(96).ToList(); // depending on your implementation, ToList may be requiered to make the actual trip to database
        }
       });
}
```

or, as suggested in comment, if you stored procedure returns IQueryable, you can simply use this code:

```
public static Task<List<ObtenerLayoutPor_Result>> GenerarArchivoPorBanco()
{
        using (CobranzaEntities db = new CobranzaEntities())
        {
            return db.ObtenerLayoutPor(96).ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

To sum up, the easiest way to make a funtion async is to wrap it in Task.Run. Then you can use it in your code:

```
var results = await GenerarArchivoPorBanco();
```

Comment: That's not the easiest, nor the most correct way of doing that. A) Don't use `Task.Run` for implementing methods, only for calling them. B) If `ObtenerLayoutPor` returns an `IQueryable<T>` as your answer suggests, using `ToListAsync` instead of `ToList` is the only proper way of doing this asynchronously.

Comment: Wraping a method in Task.Run is really implementig it, rather a shortcut to make it async. And you have a point wit ToListAsync

Comment: No, it's not, please read [this post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: I read the post, and then one linked in that one, and all they say is "it spawns new thread, it is not efficient". If you need the work done async, at some point you have to use Task.Run (or TaskFactory or whatever) - spawning new thread is the whole point of making function async. Also, question was how to do it, not if it is a good idea.